# Can we set a SpanText tappable in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```dart
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: 'NEW USER ?',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: '  SIGN UP',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Here, I wanna do something when the "SIGN UP" is tapped.

Comment: pass `GestureRecognizer recognizer` in the construcor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TextSpan` has `recognizer` property to tap on the given widget.

```
TextSpan(
         text: '  SIGN UP',
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
         )    
recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
            // do something here
    }),
)
```